# Online Syntax highlighter: url, robots.txt, .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, syntax-highlighting, robots.txt

Does someone know some good online syntax highlighter

to highlight `urls`, `robots.txt`, `.htaccess`?

I'm looking around the web but I can't find anything of good..

In the past I have used "codemirror", but unfortunately it does not support them..

Hope there is some good solution, thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Unix based system, you might want to take a look at [vim](http://www.vim.org/) which has syntaxhighlighting for .htaccess files and robots.txt files. On Windows you could try [Notepad](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)++ in combination with some [additions](https://plus.google.com/+Easytouch/posts/PaW4GK6om2K).